# How to use parameters in class view and url?

Tags: python, django

I want to get parameter from template.
But when I do it gives an error:

> TypeError at /report/2000-01-01/2022-08-12/Investigations/
> wrapper_func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

It takes the parameters true but I think I can't pass them to the views. How can I do it?

**views.py**

```
class GroupingReportsPage(ReportsMixin, ListView):
    model = ProcessType
    def case_groups(date_1, date_2, process_group):
        fieldname = 'case_type_value'
        cases = Case.objects.filter(date_created__range=[date_1, date_2])
        process_types = ProcessType.objects.filter(reporting_group__option=process_group)
        report_group = {}
        print('cases')
        print('cases')
        print(cases)
        print(process_types)
        return cases

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print('sadasds')
        self.case_groups()
        context['query_trend'] = 'query_trend'
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
path('report/<str:date_1>/<str:date_2>/<str:process_group>/', report.GroupingReportsPage.as_view(), name='process_groups'),
```

**template**

```
<a href="{% url 'fdm:process_groups' date_1 date_2 index %}" style="color: black">
                    {{index}}
                </a>
```

**traceback**
Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/report/2000-01-01/2022-08-12/Investigations/

Django Version: 3.2.14
Python Version: 3.8.9
Installed Applications:
['bvb',
 'fdm',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'guardian',
 'admin_reorder',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_filters',
 'drf_auto_endpoint',
 'jsonschemaform',
 'adminsortable2',
 'auditlog',
 'django_htmx',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django_celery_beat',
 'pgtrigger',
 'fdm_data',
 'front',
 'magic',
 'exchangelib',
 'django_sass',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'admin_reorder.middleware.ModelAdminReorder',
 'auditlog.middleware.AuditlogMiddleware',
 'django_htmx.middleware.HtmxMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ed/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/ed/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/ed/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ed/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ed/PycharmProjects/fm/decorators/roles.py", line 20, in wrapper_func
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ed/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py", line 71, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ed/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ed/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/django/views/generic/list.py", line 157, in get
    context = self.get_context_data()
  File "/Users/ed/PycharmProjects/fm/views/report.py", line 680, in get_context_data
    self.case_groups()

Exception Type: TypeError at /report/2000-01-01/2022-08-12/Investigations/
Exception Value: case_groups() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'date_1', 'date_2', and 'process_group'
```

Comment: Can you please add the whole traceback. Where is this error getting raised?

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_context_data(self, request, **kwargs):
```

Try to change your function declaration to include `request` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but this is probably caused by missing `self` parameter in custom method (which is not static).

Change this:

```py
def case_groups(date_1, date_2, process_group):
```

To this:

```py
@staticmethod
def case_groups(date_1, date_2, process_group):
```